# Convert `jest.mock` to `mockImplementationOnce`

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

I am trying to mock this multiple times

```tsx
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";

export function getAuthenticatedUser() {
  try {
    const jwt = Cookies.get("access_token");
    return jwtDecode(jwt);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(`Invalid token`, e);
    return null;
  }
}
```

This code works but I wont be able to change `jwt-decode` behavior

```tsx
jest.mock("jwt-decode", () => () => ({
  exp: Infinity,
}));
```

I think I should use `mockImplementationOnce` but it's not working so far

```tsx
jest.mock("jwt-decode", () =>
  jest
    .fn()
    .mockImplementationOnce(() =>
      Promise.resolve({
        exp: Infinity,
      })
    )
    .mockImplementationOnce(() =>
      Promise.resolve({
        exp: Infinity,
      })
    )
);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What error did you get? What do you expect

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `Promise.resolve`

```tsx
jest.mock("jwt-decode", () =>
  jest
    .fn()
    .mockImplementationOnce(() => {
      return { exp: Infinity };
    })
    .mockImplementationOnce(() => {
      return { exp: Infinity };
    })
    .mockImplementationOnce(() => {
      return new Error("Token is not valid");
    })
);
```